# What is the most idiomatic way to implement a two-method, non-getter-setter interface in ByteBuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

I have a slightly odd interface to implement using ByteBuddy.  Let's say it looks like this:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
  public T getBar();
  public void setBarSupplier(final BarSupplier supplier);
}
```

What is the most idiomatic way to implement this interface from within a `DynamicType.Builder`?  Assume that I've already defined a `private` field of type `BarSupplier`, and that:

1. I need the implementation of `setBarSupplier(BarSupplier)` to set this field and
2. I need the implementation of `getBar()` to invoke some method (let's pretend it's `get()`) on the `BarSupplier` stored in this field and return its result

I am aware of the `intercept(Implementation)` method, which takes (as you can see) a single `Implementation`.  For getter/setter pairs, this works great, because you can pass in a `FieldAccessor` and the `FieldAccessor` will generate *two* methods: the getter and the setter.  (This is not applicable in my case: I need two distinctly different method implementations.)

I'm also aware of simply defining methods by hand using `defineMethod()` and I'm prepared to do that if that's the proper way to do things.

However, I am unsure if methods defined in this manner will lack some kind of necessary association with the interface that defined them (the fact that `implement` returns an object that has a single `intercept` method makes me think this is the only way to properly implement an interface).  Will my dynamic class still implement `Foo<T>` if I don't use the `intercept` chained to the `implement` method and just define my methods by hand?  (As with all DSLs, I am faced with a fork in the road here and no map: do I pick `implement` or do I pick `defineMethod`?  How do I know?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `defineMethod`, Byte Buddy would detect the override but it's probably easier to implement the interface to then use `.method(...)` matchers, for example by name. You could even go as far as matching `.method(Foo.class.getMethod(...))` if you want to avoid any ambigouities.